# Refresh a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to write some log text in a UITextview. e.g.: x image is loaded, y object created etc. 
My problem is: the UITextView doesn't refresh after a line is inserted. I think that when the insertion ends all new texts are displayed in the same time.

```
append = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@ file is dowloading...", refreshName]
logTextView.text = [logTextView.text stringByAppendingString: append];
```

After download I save the file and

```
append = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@ file saved", refreshName];
logTextView.text = [logTextView.text stringByAppendingString: append];
```

I tried

```
[logTextView setNeedsDisplay]
```

or

```
[logTextView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

but it didn't work :(

Session would be:

1. Insert new line to textview (downloading)
2. Show this text
3. Download file (few seconds)
4. Insert new line to the UITextView (download finished)
5. Show the text

What it happens is:

1. Download the file (few sec.)
2. UITextView show lines (downloadig, download finished)

Comment: you may know the solution for my problem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864100/how-do-i-reprint-refresh-the-uitextview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text will only update the next time through the main thread's runloop. If you have a long running task on the main loop, and it keeps writing to the textView, then nothing is going to get displayed before your task ends.

I can think of a few ways to fix this:

- run the big task on the normal dispatch queue, and message back to the textView using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), append this new text); The idea is your task is performed on a secondary thread (so it cannot directly message the UI) but updates the UI by sending short blocks to the main queue.
- break your big task into chunks, each of which can be initiated by a method. In this case you do the first one on the main queue, then dispatch a block to the main queue with the updated UITextView text, and following that the next chunk of work to be done. That is:

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
  {
      update textView text;
      [self doTask1:maybeSomeDictionary];
  }

when doTask1 completes, its dispatches the next block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    update textView text again;
    [self doTask2:maybeSomeDictionary];
}
```

When the final task finishes then you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there's no way to refresh immediately textview :(

Comment: I downloadig about 10-20 images from internet... it takes 10-12 seconds... until the textview is empty :(
I worked many years in windows platform... I update label, memo or something in big task and I call during in method application.processmessages - components are refresh.
I see...the time has come to I write multi-threaded programs :)

Comment: There are hundreds of frameworks and projects you can find on github that provide threaded downloads. I have one I've tried to make as small as possible, and as easy to incorporate as possible: github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy - you'll see how to create a queue, concurrent operation, etc. Its a small project few files. It messages you back on the mainThread so you can update the UI easily. Even if you don't end up using it, you will better understand how to use a concurrent NSOperation in a background thread.

Comment: Nice code :) I try to understand your code thanks. I'm beginer in Objective-C and Mac world :). I started 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Hah - I've been doing it for 8 years now (first Mac then iOS). Its a steep climb at first, then it levels out and you gain speed. Good luck!